# Justification of discarding the backward wave in step potential scattering

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, scattering, s-matrix-theory

I'm following Shankar's treatment of 1D scattering in *Principles of Quantum Mechanics* (Page 167 to Page 172).

In general, the eigenstates of the single-step potential $$V(x)=\begin{cases}
0   & \text{for } x < 0 \\
V_0 & \text{for } x > 0
\end{cases}$$
is:
$$\psi(x)=\begin{cases}
A_1 e^{-i k_1 x} + B_1 e^{i k_1 x} & \text{for } x < 0 \\
A_2 e^{-i k_2 x} + B_2 e^{i k_2 x} & \text{for } x > 0
\end{cases}.$$

But we simply set $A_2 = 0$ to get the desired scattering states. That is, we discard the backward wave. Is it merely a consequence of physical intuition or classical analogy? Or there are some deeper reasons?

Also, if I'm considering a Gaussian wave packet which it initially far away from $x = 0$ and is heading right towards $x = 0$. In Shankar's book, we first calculate its projection along all scattering states. Does this mean that the Gaussian wave packet doesn't have a component with $A_2 \neq 0$?

Comment: It is perhaps, worth nothing, that the above case for $\psi(x)$ is only ever the general case corresponding to $V(x)$ whenever $E\gt V(x)$, $\forall x\gt 0$; so as to preclude any possibility of tunneling solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, we don't set $A_2=0$ - we set $B_2=0$.

Our ability to do this is essentially a boundary condition. Because the Schrodinger equation is a 2nd order linear differential equation, there will be two linearly independent solutions -  or equivalently, two undetermined constants in the most general solution for a given energy.

By setting $A_1=1, B_2= 0$ by hand, we are picking one solution which physically corresponds to a wave propagating to the right in region 1 $(A_1)$ which is then partially reflected $(B_1)$ and partially transmitted $(A_2)$. We can obtain the other solution by setting $A_1 = 0, B_2 = 1$ in which case we would be studying a wave propagating to the left in region 2 $(B_2)$ which is then partially reflected $(A_2)$ and partially transmitted $(B_1)$. The most general solution is then some linear combination of these two.

---

To understand the issue mathematically, we can simply set $V_0= 0$ to make the Hamiltonian that of a free particle. To solve for the generalized eigenfunctions, we may set $A_1=0,B_2=0$ and enforce continuity of the wavefunction and its derivative to yield
$$\matrix{1+B_1 = A_2\\k(1-B_1)=kA_2}\implies \matrix{A_2=1\\B_1=0}\implies \psi = e^{ikx}\text{ everywhere}$$
To find the other, we can set $A_1 = 0, B_2 = 1$ to yield
$$\matrix{B_1 = A_2+1\\-kB_1=k(A_2-1)}\implies \matrix{A_2=0\\B_1=1}\implies \psi = e^{-ikx}\text{ everywhere}$$

This is not the only way we could have done this, of course. For example, we could have set $A_1=B_1=1$ and $A_1 = -B_1=1$ to yield the cosine and sine solutions, respectively. But they can be equivalently expressed with complex exponentials, so this is just a different way of writing the same thing.

Comment: I understand that, but my question is, why can't we have a backward wave on the other side (since only the transmitted wave is included in our eigen-states), is this only by physical consideration or there are some deeper reasons.

Comment: @JasonChen You *can* have a wave traveling to the left in the region on the right side of the barrier. You are only looking at half of the allowed eigenstates. As I said, to find the other half, we set $B_2=1$ and $A_1=0$. The reason we choose our eigenstates this way is that the choice $(A_1=1,B_2=0)$ is how we would describe a wave incident on the barrier from the left. More precisely, if we wanted to imagine a "pulse" which originates far to the left at time $t=0$ and then proceed to scatter off of the barrier, then we would build that wave packet out of eigenstates which have $B_2=0$.

Comment: If we wanted to describe a pulse which is incident on the barrier from the *right*, then we would use eigenstates which have $A_1=0$. These choices can be understood intuitively by noting that if your wave packet is initially made of components all traveling to the right, then some will be reflected (therefore traveling to the left in region 1) and some will be transmitted (and therefore travel to the right in region 2) but there is no "source" for waves traveling to the *left* in region 2.

Answer (score 1):

The general solution to Schrödinger's time-independent
equation (for energy $E$) is
$$\psi(x)=\begin{cases}
A_1 e^{-i k_1 x} + B_1 e^{i k_1 x} & \text{for } x < 0 \\
A_2 e^{-i k_2 x} + B_2 e^{i k_2 x} & \text{for } x > 0
\end{cases}.$$
It can be visualized like this.
[image]

Without loss of generality this solution can be decomposed into a sum of
two parts (with the same $k_1$ and $k_2$, but different $A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2$),
so that each part is also a solution of Schrödinger's equation.

1. An incoming wave on the left (getting transmitted and reflected),
   but without an incoming wave on the right (i.e. $A_2=0$).
   [image]
2. An incoming wave on the right (getting trasnsmitted and reflected),
   but without an incoming wave on the left (i.e. $B_1=0$).
   [image]

Now, if we want to know what happens to a wave coming from the left,
then we analyze the first part (from 1.).
This is what Shankar does in his book.

If we would want to know what happens to a wave coming from the right,
then we need analyse the second part (from 2.)

Comment: That's brilliant! Mathematically, do you mean that the two-dimensional eigen-subspace of $H$ is spanned by the two states that you draw? And since the projection of a right going Gaussian wave packet along the second state is ignorable, we can only consider the first state? (i.e. set $A_2 = 0$)

Comment: But since we can also decompose the subspace into a $B_1 = 0$ state(which is the second state that you draw) and a $A_1 = 0$ state(which is a state that has two incoming wave and one outcoming wave, physically unreasonable but mathematically acceptable). And the projection along the $B_1 = 0$ state is also small. By doing so, we seem to justify setting $A_1 = 0$?